# JQuery select span within div with id with a counter

Tags: jquery, select

I got several divs

```
  <div id="id0" class="ccc">
    <span></span>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
```

I wish to insert text to the span element of a particular div with id and I wish to do it in a loop. So, just selecting

```
$(id0)
```

does not do the job. I need something like

```
for(counter=...) {
    $('#id'+counter > span).text(...
```

None of the options tried does the trick and I m running out of ideas...

Comment: `$('#id' + counter + " > span").text(...` ??

Answer (score 1):

Use `+`(Concat operator) and concatenate `> span` as shown:-

```
for(counter=...) {
    $('#id' + counter + ' > span').text(...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $.each

```
<div id="id0" class="ccc">
    <span></span>
    <p></p>
</div>
<div id="id1" class="ccc">
    <span></span>
    <p></p>
</div>
<div id="id2" class="ccc">
    <span></span>
    <p></p>
</div>
<div id="id3" class="ccc">
    <span></span>
    <p></p>
</div>
<div id="id4" class="ccc">
    <span></span>
    <p></p>
</div>
<div id="id5" class="ccc">
    <span></span>
    <p></p>
</div>

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".ccc").each(function() {
       $(this).find("span").text("aaa"); // add text to span
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery it is easy to use the result set of the $() function to apply the same method on multiple DOM elements:

```
$(".ccc").find("span").text("text");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ht7rwa9t/